# Adding If condition to where clause in DQL / Symfony 3

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I've a doctrine entity with two variables `$price` & `$price_new` mapped to mysql table with same column name. 
`$price` contains legacy values and `$price_new` contains new values.
I want to write a query which checks if `$price_new > 0` then apply where on `$price_new` but if `$price_new = 0`, `$price` is used in where clause.

Is there any way to implement it in DQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you by chance look for something like this?

```
SELECT p
FROM App\Entity\Product p
WHERE (p.price_new > 0 AND p.price_new = :price)
    OR (p.price_new = 0 AND p.price = :price)
```

If this is in fact what you are looking for, I would suggest creating a migration that updates your table's `price` field with the new price and then you can throw out the somewhat redundant `price_new`. If you need the current state you can create a database dump and retrieve both values, but in your live system you likely only want to have one price.

The migration could look something like this (real SQL this time):

```
UPDATE product SET product.price = product.price_new WHERE product.price_new > 0;
```

Then it's a matter of removing the redundant `price_new` both in your code and in your database and you are good to go.

Comment: Let me try this. I can not remove the redundant field because it is required for fallback purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by fallback? You need both the old and new price together?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a DQL using or conditions for your criteria

```
select a
from YourBundle:Entity a
where (price_new > 0 and price_new = :price_var)
or (price_new = 0 and price = :price_var )
```

Note the parenthesis around filter criteria are important to satisfy condtions

where price_new is greater 0 then price_new = some price value if this filter returns false then next clause will check if  price_new equals 0 then price = some price value

You could use doctrine query builder but make sure you add these parenthesis